# Comparing two large text files column by column in Python

Tags: python, compare, large-files

I have two large tab separated text files with dimensions : 36000 rows x 3000 columns. The structure of the columns is same in both files but they may not be sorted.

I need to *compare only the numeric columns* between these two files(apprx 2970 columns) and export out those rows where there is a difference in the value between any two respective columns.

Problem: Memory issue

Things I tried:

1) Transposing data: Making the data from wide to long and reading the data chunk by chunk.
Problem: Data bloats to a more than few million rows and python throws me a memory error

2) Difflib: Difflib along with generators and without transposing did provide me an output which was efficient but it compares the two files row by row. It doesn't differentiate the columns in the tab separated file.(I need them to be differentiated into columns since I will be performing some column operations between the difference rows.

3) Chunk and join: This is third approach I am trying wherein I will divide one file into chunks and merge it on the common keys with the other file repeatedly and find the difference in those chunks. This is going to be a shitty approach and its going to take a lot of time but I am unable to think of any thing else.

Also: 
These type of questions have been answered in the past but they only dealt with one huge file and processing the same.

Any suggestions for a better approach in **Python** will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some code you've already written?

Comment: Do both files have exactly the same number of rows, i.e. you're always comparing row N in one file to row N in the other file?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh- I do have few codes written for each of the things I tried. It was all basic transpose and using direct functions from Difflib package. That is the reason I didnt post any code.

Comment: @JohnGordon- No, the row count can be different. Hence I was thinking of the Join approach where in I can make a small data set for each chunk and output the difference rows. But it will be slow.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if files are that big, they should be read row by row.

Reading one file row by row is simple:

```
with open(...) as f:
    for row in f:
        ...
```

To iterate two files row by row, zip them:

```
with open(...) as f1, open(...) as f2:
    for row1, row2 in itertools.izip(f1, f2):
        # compare rows, decide what to do with them
```

I used `izip`, as it won't zip everything at once, like `zip` would in Python 2.
In Python 3, use `zip`. It does the right thing there.
It will go row by row and yield the pairs.

The next question is comparing by column. Separate the columns:

```
columns = row.split('\t')  # they are separated by tabs, therefore \t
```

Now pick the relevant columns and compare them. Then discard irrelevant rows and write the relevant ones to the output.

Comment: This worked beautifully, Nice strategy. But if the files are not ordered or if they don't have the exact same data it will give a wrong output

Comment: Can this be modified to search for the record in file1 to be present anywhere in file2 and then compare?

Comment: @codemob That is a much more difficult task and the best solution depends on the details. Speaking generally, for randomly ordered rows, you either have to have the whole file in the memory (i.e. read all of it) or you have to do a lot of reading from disk. In some cases, it may make sense to read in batches (e.g. 1000 rows at a time), in other cases, if you just have to skip some rows, you can use something similar to this, but then occasionally skip a row using e.g. `next(f1)`.

Comment: If unsorted, think about using a sql database.  It will take more time, but you can then search by keys